# IntlDateFormatter return a wrong pattern

Tags: php, date, internationalization

I am using IntlDateFormatter/i18n for the first time. When I want to format a date in french, I get the right format (dd/MM/yyyy) but when I am looking for an italian format (for exemple) I get a wrong format (dd/MM/yy) instead of the same as the french one.

Is that a bug of IntlDateFormatter? Do I do something wrong?
Here is a code sample :

```
<?php
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
echo $fmt->getPattern();  // return dd/MM/yyyy

$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('it_IT', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
echo $fmt->getPattern();  // return dd/MM/yy instead of dd/MM/yyyy
```

Here are where I picked up my information, [for the date format in France and Italy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) and [for the IntlDateFormatter patterns](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Answer (score 0):

for me with php5.5 and lib-icu 4.2.1 both nations give me dd/MM/yy, so  if you want a different pattern I suggest to create an array upstream and go with your calling setPattern.

I guess the problem comes from the version of libicu in your system but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I have 52.1 under ICU Version in intl section in my phpinfo I can't find the lib-icu version like yours. Can you guide me a bit ? I'm with ubuntu 14.04. Thanks.

Comment: call phpinfo() and check intl group
I have
version 1.1.0
ICU version 4.2.1

Comment: That's it, I have intl versino 1.1.0 and ICU version 52.1... I have installed intl with via ubuntu packages (php5-intl) not pcre does it change something ?

Comment: to solve any issue related to the icu version i suggest you to set the pattern with an array with setPattern, try it:)